# Postgres: Storing output of moving average query to a column

Tags: postgresql, moving-average

I have a table in Postgres 14.2
Table name is test
There are 3 columns: date, high, and five_day_mavg (date is PK if it matters)
I have a select statement which properly calculates a 5 day moving average based on the data in high.

```
select date, 
       avg(high) over (order by date rows between 4 preceding and current row) as mavg_calc 
from test
```

It products output as such:

I have 2 goals:

1. First to store the output of the query in five_day_mavg.
2. Second to store this in such a way that when I a new row with data
   in high, it automatically calculates that value

The closest I got was:

```
update test set five_day_mavg = a.mav_calc 
from (
  select date, 
         avg(high) over (order by date rows between 4 preceding and current row) as mav_calc 
  from test
) a;
```

but all that does is sets the value of every row in five_day_mavg to entire average of high

Comment: You need some kind of join condition in your UPDATE statement `where test.pk_column = a.pk_column`

Comment: "*a way that when I add new row with data in `high`, it automatically calculates that value*" - for that you'll need a trigger

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name If you have a sample I'd be happy to try and validate.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @a_horse_with_no_name
I played around with the WHERE clause

```
update test l set five_day_mavg = b.five_day_mavg from (select date, avg(high) over (order by date rows between 4 preceding and current row) as five_day_mavg from test )b where l.date = b.date;
```

a couple of things. I defined each table. The original table I aliased as l, the temporary table created by doing a windows function (the select statement in parenthesis) I aliased as b and I joined with the WHERE clause on date which is the index/primary key.
Also, I was using 'a' as the letter for alias, and I think that may have contributed to the issue.
Either way, solved now.